# Random Function

Tags: python, function, random

I want to make a for loop with random strings in it. 
I want the names not to repeat themselves and the prices can occur twice (we were with 5 people and there were 2 drill-motor and 2 Dc-motors to give away).
So, 4 people would get a price, 2 people get the drill-motors and 2 people get the DC-motors.

How can I do this? Because when I run, the `random.sample` repeats itself every time it runs a part of the loop and some names and prices occur too often. Thus, I want the names to occur once and each price twice.

This is the code:

```
import random

price=["You have won the drill-motor" , "You have won the DC motor"]

Names = ["Hilmi", "Joris", "Isa", "Dennis", "Jasper"]

for i in range (len(Names)-1):
    print(*random.sample(Names,1), *random.sample(price,1))
```

Comment: What you're describing isn't random, but permutations. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: You might as well use `random.choice(Names)` instead of `*random.sample(Names, 1)`

Comment: FYI `price` is what you have to pay, the one you can win is called `prize`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) appropriate lists:

```
import random

names = ["Hilmi", "Joris", "Isa", "Dennis", "Jasper"]
prices = 2 * ["You have won the drill-motor" , "You have won the DC motor"]

random.shuffle(names)
random.shuffle(prices)  
# shuffling prices is not strictly necessary
# the random name order already guarantees everybody's fair chance ;)

for name, price in zip(names, prices): 
    print(name, price)

# Hilmi You have won the DC motor
# Jasper You have won the drill-motor
# Dennis You have won the DC motor
# Joris You have won the drill-motor
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the zip function, did some research and now I understand! But one more question: After I shuffle the names, each time I print names, do I always get a shuffled names list?

Comment: @jan `shuffle` does an in-place shuffle of the list. So the original list now is and remains shuffled. It does not, however, magically reshuffle everytime you print it if that's what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the names list at the beginning, and just iterate over them once.
Also [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) is the better option than [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) when only one item is chosen.
Here's the code

```
import random
price = ["You have won the drill-motor" , "You have won the DC motor"]
names = ["Hilmi", "Joris", "Isa", "Dennis", "Jasper"]
shuffled_names = names[:]  # create a copy if you want original order preserved
random.shuffle(shuffled_names)
for name in shuffled_names:
    print(name, random.choice(price))
```

Comment: This would not ensure both prices being won twice.

Comment: We don't _need_ to ensure that prices must occur twice. The question says prices *can* appear twice. Prices are allowed to appear twice. Not a necessary condition.